# Parameter pack works in msvc but not in gcc and clang

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-pack

I recently learnt about parameter packs. Then I wrote the following program that compiles with msvc but not with clang and gcc. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3ae48xzY8):

```
#include <array>

template<typename T, std::size_t... rows> int func(T (&arr...)[rows])    
{
   return 5;  
}
int main()
{
    
    int arr[2][3][4];
    auto a = func(arr);
    
}
```

As can be seen in the above demo, msvc compiles it but gcc says:

```
<source>:3:56: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
    3 | template<typename T, std::size_t... rows> int func(T (&arr...)[rows])
      |                                                        ^~~
<source>:3:69: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
    3 | template<typename T, std::size_t... rows> int func(T (&arr...)[rows])
      |                                                                     ^
<source>:3:69: note:         'rows'
<source>:6:2: error: expected ';' before 'int'
    6 | }
      |  ^
      |  ;
    7 | int main()
      | ~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

I want to know which compiler is correct and the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for a parameter pack has `...` *in front of* the declarator-id:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... rows> int func(T (&...arr)[rows])    
{
   return 5;  
}
```

This is the same for simpler parameter packs:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void test(Ts ...arr);
```

Whitespace doesn't matter and `Ts... arr` is a more common style but doesn't reflect well that `...` is part of the declarator `...arr`, not of the type specifier `Ts`.

MSVC seems to accept the syntax with `...` after the declarator-id `arr` for some reason, but that should be ill-formed. However, MSVC does give it the same meaning as the correct order would, see below.

---

But it doesn't have the meaning you intent it to have. `T (&...arr)[rows]` expands to a list of parameters of the form `T (&arr1)[rows1], T (&arr2)[rows2], T (&arr3)[rows3]` and so on. You can't add `[rowsN]` syntax to a parameter's type with a pack expansion.

In your call `auto a = func(arr);`, `T` will be `int[3][4]` and `rows` will have a single element with value `2`.

Answer (score 2):

The program is **ill-formed** because when introducing a function parameter pack the ellipsis `...` that expands a template parameter pack must appear prior to or in place of the function parameter name.

In other words, the `...` should be placed before the function parameter name `b` so that the corrected program would look like:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------vvv------------>prior to function parameter name 
template<typename T, std::size_t... rows> int func(T (&...arr)[rows])    
{
   return 5;  
}
int main()
{
    
    int arr[2][3][4];
    auto a = func(arr);
    
}
```