# Template parameter pack works in gcc but not in msvc

Tags: c++

I wrote the following program that has a template parameter pack `Indices` for academic purposes. But the problem is that msvc rejects it but gcc and clang accepts it.

I want to know which compiler is right here? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdx75jjfK)

```
#include<cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t...Indices>
void func(T (&)[sizeof...(Indices)]);
int main()
{
    int arr[4];
    func<int, 1,2,3,4>(arr);  //msvc rejects but clang and gcc accepts
}
```

MSVC says:

```
source>(11): error C2182: 'func': this use of 'void' is not valid
<source>(11): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
<source>(11): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
<source>(13): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
<source>(13): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Note that I am not looking for a workaround.

Comment: It's odd that MSVC doesn't seem to have any problem as long as the template parameters are deduced though ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/99n58xfGG)). Perhaps specifying template parameters in this situation is so uncommon that it's not even tested.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Here's another [old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75705667/12002570) that at the time of the post used to compile(incorrectly) with msvc. Seems like msvc no longer compiles that now and that has been fixed.

Comment: @user12002570 yeah, I had seen that one and voted there too at the time it was written :-)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a msvc bug. The program is well-formed.

Here is the newly reported bug:

[MSVC rejects valid program involving template paramter pack taking array by reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-involving-tem/10628323)